# Touch a sprite without boundingBox

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

So i'm trying to move multiple sprites on the screen at the same time. The problem is that if the 2 sprites are close to each other the position becomes the same (so the bounding box is the same) and i can't seem to pull them apart.

I'm using the "standard" `CGRectContainsPoint(sprite1.boundingBox,location)`.

What i need is to get the sprite on top regardless of boundingBox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hah..i fixed in the easiest way possible :\

```
 if (CGRectContainsPoint (sprite1.boundingBox,location)){
 sprite1.position=location;
 }else if (CGRectContainsPoint (sprite2.boundingBox,location)){
 sprite2.position=location;
 }
```

the way this behaves is that if the bounding boxes are the same..it only takes one..not the 2nd one

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to start assigning explicit z values to sprites you add, using `CCNode`'s `-(void) addChild: (CCNode*)node z:(NSInteger)z` method.

Then, when you get multiple sprites back from your bounding test, only move the one with largest z value.

Comment: your answer gave me the idea how to fix it..so..it's not technically an answer..but good advice in any case :) thx

Comment: @skytz It's definitely technically an answer, just not your accepted answer, which is totally fine! =)  Glad it helped in some way.

Comment: What i meant is that it's not exactly the answer i was looking for... :)